# confused on how to used pointers and vector pointers

Tags: c++

I am confused on how to use pointers and vector pointers to perform the correct operation.

I want to pass elements of vector `Vec` to struct function `updateHeap`. `updateHeap` modifies the value of these members. I can't quite achieve this result with my code below. I have commented sections in my code to explain my problem better.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() : hLoc(100){}
    A(int av, int bv):a(av),b(bv),hLoc(100){}

    int a, b;
    int hLoc;
};

struct Heap
{
    Heap() : heapMembers(new std::vector<A>) {}

    Heap(std::vector<A> *members) : heapMembers(members) {}

    void updateHeap(unsigned int idx)
    {
        (*heapMembers)[idx].a*=2;   
    }

    std::vector<A> *heapMembers; //ptr
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> aVec;  
    //I want to use updateHeap function in struct Heap to modify values of select elements of aVec


    A a0(2,5), a1(4,2), a2(8,4);  
        aVec.push_back(a0); aVec.push_back(a1); aVec.push_back(a2); 
        //Here I initialized aVec


    Heap minHeap1;
    //In minHeap1, I want to add elements one by one

    minHeap1.heapMembers->push_back(aVec[1]); 
    //I added a selected element (aVec[1]) in aVec to the heap; 
    minHeap1.updateHeap(minHeap.heapMembers->size()-1); 
    //I want to modify the value of aVec[1].a by calling updateHeap function
    std::cout << aVec[1].a << "\n";
    //Output: 4 , I want this value to be 2*4=8. 

    std::vector<A> heapVec;  
    heapVec.push_back(a1);

    Heap minHeap2(&heapVec);
    //In minHeap2, I want to give it a vector of selected elements
    minHeap2.updateHeap(minHeap2.heapMembers->size()-1);
    //I want to modify the value of aVec[1].a by calling updateHeap function
    std::cout <<    aVec[1].a << "\n";
    //Output: 4 , I want this value to be 2*4=8.
    std::cout << heapVec[0].a << "\n";
    //Output: 8 , This is the right answer, but I want aVec[1].a to take upon this value

    delete minHeap1.heapMembers;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Heap(std::vector<A> *members) // A reference will do it

Comment: You have a few errors in the code. I'm correcting them, since they are quite trivial.

Comment: @jogojapan, I'm sorry. I'm new to the forum and c++. I was trying to vote on peoples answers but it kept telling me that I need 15 points to vote. I googled how to close a thread thinking that is how to show the answer is accepted, but saw that that is not in my hands. I didn't realize the check meant answer accepted. I'll do that right now. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `vector::push_back()` copies the pushed element into the vector; it does not push a reference nor anything like that. So after:

```
minHeap1.heapMembers->push_back(aVec[1]);
```

`(*minHeap1.heapMembers)[0]` will be a copy of `aVec[1]`. Changing that (as you do in `Heap::updateHeap()`) changes the copy, not the original.

If you want to be able to change `aVec` through `minHeap1`, you will need to actually use that vector inside the heap (more or less what you do with `heapVec` and `minHeap2`) or change the vector inside `Heap` so it does not contain values, but references or pointers. You cannot have an `std::vector` of references, so you will have to do with pointers:

```
struct Heap
{
    Heap() : heapMembers(new std::vector<A*>) {}

    Heap(std::vector<A*> *members) : heapMembers(members) {}

    void updateHeap(unsigned int idx)
    {
        (*heapMembers)[idx]->a*=2;   
    }

    std::vector<A*> *heapMembers; //ptr
};
```

And then, in your `main()` function:

```
minHeap1.heapMembers->push_back(&aVec[1]);
```

Of course, this will create some problems with the lifetime of the elements pointed to by the pointers inside `heapMembers`, but your `main()` will work as long as you take care to make `heapVec` also an `std::vector<A*>`.

Comment: @Gorpic, thank you. I made the changes to `minHeap2` also based on your answer and now it works. Can you please clarify by what you mean about the lifetime of the elements? It might help if I tell you that I would like to constantly add and remove `heapMembers` elements, but my `aVec` will always have the same numver of elements.

Comment: @namu When you push `&aVec[1]`, inside your heap there will be a pointer to an element that was created outside it. This pointer will become invalid when that element (`aVec[1]`) is destroyed. This may happen when `aVec` itself is destroyed, but also when you add an element to it (pointers to elements in an `std::vector` become invalid when you add new elements) or when you remove that element from the vector. In your `main()` you don't do any of these things, but you have to be very careful in other circumstances.